# How to Selectivly Passthrough USB devices to a chroot

Tags: ubuntu, mount, usb, chroot, fuse

I have a chrooted env. made with `debootstrap` and i would like to pass only **Certain** USB devices to it. (not all the devices mounted on the host system).

I know you could pass all `USB` devices by using

`$ sudo mount --bind /dev chroot/dev`

`$ sudo mount --bind /sys chroot/sys`

But i would like to have more control to allow passing only certain USB devices.
I thought about writing some script with `FUSE` that achieves  what `mnt --bind` does but with more control over what to mirror and what to leave out.

But i wanted to ask to see if there are available tools that do this.

many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If there are apps running under the root user in your chroot, everything you're doing is pointless, as root can create device nodes. In case you don't have them, you could simply

```bsh
sudo cp -a /dev chroot
```

and then delete the devices files you don't want to have in the chroot. After all `/dev` devices are just special files `cp` can perfectly work with.